# open socket with url with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

Below I attached the code to the example of working with api. 
How translate this code from js to python?

```
const socketToken = '';

  //Connect to socket
  const data= io(`https://sockets.data.com?token=${socketToken}`);


  data.on('event', (eventData) => {
    if (!eventData.for && eventData.type === '') {     
      console.log(eventData.message);
    }
    if (eventData.for === 'test') {
      switch(eventData.type) {
        case '1':          
          console.log(eventData.message);
          break;
        case '2':
          console.log(eventData.message);
          break;
        default:          
          console.log(eventData.message);
      }
    }.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried converting it from JS to Python yourself? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: @disinfor yea, of couse. im tried with sockets lib, but to connect socket we need to know host and port.. but there only url.. like this: s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))

Comment: @ОлегОрлов You must post your Python attempt *in the question*. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Read the Python documentation for socket some more.  (https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)   It is all there if you look.  (But don't do it that way!)

You are apparently trying to connect to an HTTPS server.  Doing that with socket-level I/O is a huge amount of extra work for (almost) zero pay-off.  You should instead be using a HTTP / HTTPS library (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html).  That will deal with the the HTTP protocol handling and also the SSL / TLS negotiation that needs to happen with HTTPS.  And if you are trying to "do" WebSockets, there are libraries for that too.

---

**UPDATE** - I didn't recognize what you were trying to do.  While I stick to my advice for *general* HTTP / HTTPS work in Python, the "socketIO" library is a better fit in this case; see @kichik's answer.

As general advice, if you are trying to use an existing protocol or service, the first thing you should do is look for a library or binding for that particular library.  Implementing "from scratch" should be your last resort.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to connect to [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) with Python. There is a [library for that](https://github.com/invisibleroads/socketIO-client).

Install it using:

```
pip install socketIO-client
```

Then use with something like this:

```
socketToken = '....'

from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

def on_connect():
    print('connect')

def on_disconnect():
    print('disconnect')

def on_reconnect():
    print('reconnect')

def on_event(*args):
    print('on_event', args)

socketIO = SocketIO('https://sockets.data.com?token=%s' % (socketToken,))
socketIO.on('connect', on_connect)
socketIO.on('disconnect', on_disconnect)
socketIO.on('reconnect', on_reconnect)
socketIO.on('event', on_event)
socketIO.wait()
```